# Loop through captions and do something to all captions over certain character length jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I know how to count characters: `$('.caption-text p').text().length` ,   I know to add a class to an element : `$('.caption-text p').css('color', "yellow");`, I'm pretty sure I know how to write an if, or at least I hope so.  But i'm failing at connecting all of those inside a loop.

I need to loop through all the .caption-text paragraph tags, and add a color to those less than 5 characters.

I think I'm close, but any help is very appreciated!!!

```
captions = $('.caption-text p');
captions.each(function(){
  if (captions.text().length < 5){
    $(this).css('color', "yellow");
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to `this` within the each loop:

```
captions = $('.caption-text p');
captions.each(function(){
  if ($(this).text().length < 5){
    $(this).css('color', "yellow");
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2PYgh/1/

Comment: You don't need to mess with `this` (in case you want to call another function that changes what `this` means). You can instead do `...each(function(index,element){ /* element is the element for this iteration */ })`

Comment: @ShadowCreeper, within the `each` loop, `this` will refer to the current element. Yes you could name it, but this is really out of the scope of this question and unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @smemy You are right, `this` refers to the element, but `jQuery`'s `each` function was built to pass it along as a parameter. You might think `jQuery('.foo').each(my.namespace.FooHandler.handleFoo);` would have a different `this` (such as `my.namespace.FooHandler`). If you use the parameters that the `each` method provides, you will remove the ambiguity surrounding the definition of `this`.

Comment: @ShadowCreeper, jquery each loops are almost always very small and there isn't much ambiguity in that - atleast in my opinion, and in cases such as these, there is no reason to make it more verbose. Regardless of whether you name it or not, `this` will refer to the current element within the loop (it will not be a persisted `this` value from outside the loop). The only time you'd need to create another pointer to the element would be if you have another (sub function) within the each function and you need to access it from within that function.